# k8s: Is it possible to have two identical deployments but route different traffic to them?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

Here is my use case:

I have a microservice which gets sent traffic via an ingress gateway in real time and via a batch process. What I'd like to be able to do is be able to conceptually define a `deployment` and have it create two sets of pods:

- One set for real time request
- Another for batch.

When a new version of the microservice gets deployed, the k8s deployment is updated and both real time and batch use the new version.

Is this possible in k8s or will I need to create two deployments and manage them separately?

Comment: you can add more than one container to a pod.

Comment: If the pods are all identical, how exactly would the deployment know which requests to direct to which pods? Presumably the pods would need different settings or connection strings?

Comment: Pods are identical. What I'm to guard against is a glut of batch requests getting in the way of realtime requests.

Comment: Anyway it seems not possible as you want - to run some sets of pods under one deployment. A deployment is a higher abstraction that manages one or more replicasets to provide controlled rollout of a new version. "PodTemplates are specifications for creating Pods, and are included in workload resources such as Deployments, Jobs, and DaemonSets.

Each controller for a workload resource uses the PodTemplate inside the workload object to make actual Pods. The PodTemplate is part of the desired state of whatever workload resource you used to run your app." Just one PodTemplate for Deployment.

Comment: This sounds like something that Istio could help with. If a service is defined as a VirtualService, you can route to different DestinationRule objects depending on header values (or other qualifications).

Comment: Is it a production traffic for both of pods? Can you explain what is the reason for the traffic split between them? Are you already using Istio?

Comment: Yes, production traffic for both sets of pods. The rational is I'd to be able to prioritise realtime traffic over batch.

Answer (score 0):

*This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.*

Since we don't know the complete information about the architecture used, the following suggestions from comments can be used in the future to solve the problem.

**1. With Deployments, Services, Selectors**

You can have two identical deployments and route different traffic to them.
It may be implemented by [Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/):

> In Kubernetes, a Service is an abstraction which defines a logical set
> of Pods and a policy by which to access them (sometimes this pattern
> is called a micro-service). The set of Pods targeted by a Service is
> usually determined by a [selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/).

Such approach has some advantages.

- By default, traffic will be routed to endpoints in random way if you are using [iptables proxy mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-iptables). When you try to send traffic to specific pods covered by the same deployment - it may happen large differences in [CPU and Memory usage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/) leading to the resource exhaustion or wasting resources.
- It will be easier to manage service versioning, CPU and Memory assignment and rollouts.

**2. With Istio**

From [David M. Karr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10508/david-m-karr)

> If a service is defined as a [VirtualService](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#virtual-services), you can route to
> different [DestinationRule](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#destination-rules) objects depending on header values (or other
> qualifications).

**Additionally**

If you need to deploy a new version of the microservice, you can choose between different [strategies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#strategy), which is more suitable for your needs.
[Kubernetes deployment strategies](https://blog.container-solutions.com/kubernetes-deployment-strategies):

> - recreate: terminate the old version and release the new one
> - ramped: release a new version on a rolling update fashion, one after the other
> - blue/green: release a new version alongside the old version then switch traffic
> - canary: release a new version to a subset of users, then proceed to a full rollout
> - a/b testing: release a new version to a subset of users in a precise way (HTTP headers, cookie, weight, etc.). A/B testing is
>   really a technique for making business decisions based on statistics
>   but we will briefly describe the process. This doesn’t come out of the
>   box with Kubernetes, it implies extra work to setup a more advanced
>   infrastructure ([Istio](https://www.istio.io/), [Linkerd](https://linkerd.io/),  [Traefik](https://traefik.io/), custom nginx/haproxy, etc).